# Call to undefined method Query\Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a protected function that I want to use to check my login validation. However I am getting the error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::loginValidation
```

Do I have to write a model for my function?

**Login Validation:**

```
protected function loginValidation($data)
{
    $rules = array(
      'fname' => 'required|max:255',
      'lname'  => 'required|max:255',
      'email'      => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
      'password'   => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
);
    return Validator::make($data, $rules);
}
```

**getLoginCredentials**

```
  protected function getLoginCredentials(Request $request)
  {
    $validator = User::loginValidation(Request::all());

    if($validator->passes())
    {
    return[
    'email'    => Request::input('email'),
    'password' => Request::input('password'),
    'type'     => 1  
    ];

    return true;
    }else{
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the user model can not see your function. Do **composer dump-autoload** to see if the changes will reflect. if it does not try a new name and see if it will work.